# How to excute .bat script on windows from node js

Tags: windows, node.js, batch-file

I have node js file which will excute my bat file. I tried using exec of node js child-process module but no luck

Let me share you my node js script:

```
var startTime = '2014-11-27 17:0:42';
var threadName = '<Thread 0>';
var categoryName ='AlarmCategory';
var alarmLevel = 'Fatal';
var alarmCategory = 'OS';
var alarmMessage = 'corrupt';

var cp = require('child_process');
msg = cp.exec('handler.bat' +" " + startTime ,function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error.stack);
        console.log('Error code: '+error.code);
        console.log('Signal received: '+error.signal);
    }
    console.log('Child Process STDOUT: '+stdout);
    console.log('Child Process STDERR: '+stderr);
});
```

My bat script . This script takes input parms and echos.

```
 @echo off
set startTime=%1
set thread=%2
set categoryName=%3
set alarmLevel=%4
set alarmCategory=%5
set alarmMessage=%6
Echo #####################
Echo This tool will help you get the users info
Echo #####################
Echo hi %arg1%
```

For now i am printing only one arg.

Error i am getting :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 8.0.4\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" test\test_cmd.js
Error: Command failed: 'handler.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557461/execute-a-batch-file-from-nodejs

Comment: I view that link before, creating or cheking for environment is bit heavy. I am sure soething can be done using command only. I am missing soemthing silly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved my issue. I am using execFile() function now since i also need to pass arguments. It is very important to note that when you use execute command using execFile() make sure you set the "cwd" option in command of exeFile(). Since it looks for the child process file and it does not find the file. Setting full path directly for .bat file do not work .

I did like this ,

```
msg = cp.execFile('handler.bat' ,[startTime,threadName] ,{cwd:'/Node Js/baflog/sigma-logger/test'},function (error, stdout, stderr) {
.... ..
...
}
```